# Is there a way to add a pause in the "Dial Number" script of the Shoretel phones?

Tags: iphone, shoretel

First of all, my apologies if this is the wrong forum for this question, but I didn't see another forum I could place this in.

I'm trying to program a Shoretel 655 IP phone to dial a phone number, pause 1 or 2 seconds, and then enter an access code. I have been able to make it dial a number, however, I cannot find any documentation on adding a pause to the number. I'm looking for something like you are able to do with a modem dial string: ATDT91234567890,,1234.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: There is no real code. It's a device that allows you to enter a phone number. My question is if there is a way to enter a pause. I don't see anything on the keyboard that would allow that - the hash sign is used by most conferencing systems to indicate the end of entry, so that's an unlikely candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add pauses to ShoreTel speed dials either through the phone or the Director interface.